# How to make a roux?

Tags: sauce, roux

Whenever I try to make a roux according to one of the recipes I find online the consistency seems  a little off. Should the roux be completely thick or should it have a less solid consistency? I seem to read that a roux should start with equal parts butter and flour.

Comment: `Rue` means something quite unrelated to cooking. ;) I suspect you mean `roux`. Hopefully someone can edit this in.

Comment: ahaha thanks, Noldorin and Bob. I need another lesson in spelling.

Comment: Check this overlapping question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9119/how-do-i-make-my-roux-taste-less-like-flour/9121#9121

Comment: @bikeboy389 : I would've said this one was a closer match, as it's more related to the fat-to-flour ratio which directly affects thickness : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9300/minimum-amount-of-fat-in-roux

Comment: @Noldorin: rue is in fact a herb, so has a fair amount to do with cooking. FYI.

Comment: @daniel: That's not it's usual meaning. It's certainly not the meaning here. Say "rue" to most people and they'll think of sorrow/regret.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A roux normally is equal parts fat and flour.  It should be fairly solid, not runny.  However, it is an individual decision.  I've known guys who like it quite solid (like me), but you have to whisk the hell out of it to get out all of the lumps.  Normally, if I am making a sauce or soup that I can't strain, I will make it a little slack.  I also add my roux after so I can control the thickness of the sauce or soup.  Normally you are not instructed to do so, but you have greater control.  If you do it this way, you have to vigorously whisk while adding, or the starches will congeal together in lumps.  No big deal if it you are able to strain, but...

Comment: Note that "fat" (lard) is commonly replaced with butter (which contains fat of course) in modern cooking.

Comment: Replaced with? The classic French roux has always been butter, but any fat will do; I have made roux with bacon, duck, turkey, chicken, beef, and goose fats, as well as olive, peanut, canola, and soy oils.